As we redirected to record detail page i want to redirect it back to report from which we clicked the hyperlink
Hi All I am using a formula(Hyperlink) field which calls a vf page and that vf calls a screen flow when we submit the form it should redirect us to the report page from where we clicked on the hyperlink. I am able to redirect it to record detail page of record which is not my goal i need to redirect it to report page can someone help me to overcome this.
Formula is as follow.
HYPERLINK(
"https://" & MID($Api.Partner_Server_URL_370, 9, FIND('/', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_370, 9) - 9) &
"/apex/Research_UpdateNotesfromLink?ResearchID=" & Id & 
"&retURL=/" & Id,
"Update Notes",
"_blank")

Vf Page  Is
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" standardcontroller="Data_Sources__c" lightningStyleSheets="true">
<flow:interview name="Research_Update_Rep_Notes" finishLocation="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL}">
</flow:interview></apex:page>

We are using retURL because we are testing it in desktop as well as in salesforce mobile app. which wont support many things.
I tried to use something like Window.history.back() which we use in lightning but it didn't work here.
Also we are not using report Id directly because we have multiple reports and if we specify any report id it will show same report to their output.
